# Im trying to fetch images from RandomUser API, but my application is crashing

Tags: android, retrofit

```
public Retrofit imageServer() {
      return new Retrofit.Builder()                
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())                
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())               
                    .baseUrl("https://randomuser.me/api"
                    .build();   
}
```

Don't know what went wrong with my code. Kindly let me know how to fix it?

Many Thanks!

Comment: What is exactly the crash?

Comment: When I exceute ".baseUrl("https://randomuser.me/api")"  this line, the application stops running.

Comment: Could you post the error stack trace from logcat?

Comment: 06-08 11:42:26.770 465-465/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 13
06-08 11:42:26.770 465-465/? E/PPDaemon: Diag_LSM_Init() failed.
    Initialization diag library failed
    Failed to open file descriptors and register diag lib
    Unable to initialize DCM
06-08 11:42:26.770 482-486/? E/rpmb_emmc: ----------------------------rpmb_emmc_read-----------------------------
06-08 11:42:26.848 406-475/? E/keymaster1_device: HwKmClose
06-08 11:42:27.170 528-532/? E/BootAnimation: couldn't find audio_conf.txt

Comment: is the url  valid?